# Background does not spans entirely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

I had made css pre-loader which has a some-colored background and a bouncing ball. The background however doesn't spans the window entirely.The page before which the preloader appears is scrollable, and when I try to reload the page, the preloader background doesn't cover the entire page, but only till the window size from the top.
The preloader code was mentioned in this question: [Preloader does not fade out online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442664/preloader-does-not-fade-out-online)
Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;` and add `width: 100%;`.

If it doesn't fill the whole page use `height: 100vh;` instead of a percentage value.

So `#loader` should look something like this:

```
#loader  {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #0f2338;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: Worked! callous mistake.

Comment: No worries! What was your mistake if I may ask? :)